Google drive CSV ingestion to BigQuery on recurring
I want to integrate Google Drive with BigQuery to automatically load new CSV files into the database every week. These CSV files will have the same structure and should be added to BigQuery without overwriting previous weeks' data. This way, I can easily track and analyze data over time.
What are some potential approaches to achieve this? I'm not a data engineering expert, so a clear explanation would be greatly appreciated.
I have already read through some other stackoverflow tickets but they discuss more about querying the data or doing it one time for CSV file stored in Google drive.

I'd start by creating a specification.  For example, does your Drive file have the same name/location each week?  How will the new data file be found?  Can we assume that if we look for that file at a specific time (3:00am on a Sunday morning) it can be found?  Likely the solution will be a recipe that is scheduled ... 1. look for a drive file, 2. Create an external table definition for the new file, 3. Run a SQL INSERT from the data in the file (mapped table)

Have you tried to create an external table pointing to google drive? all changes will be reflected immediately in the table in BQ. Here you have the documentation https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-drive#bq.
bq mk
--external_table_definition=SCHEMA@SOURCE_FORMAT=DRIVE_URI \
DATASET.TABLE

Where:
SCHEMA is the schema definition in the format
FIELD:DATA_TYPE,FIELD:DATA_TYPE.
SOURCE_FORMAT is CSV, NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON, AVRO, or GOOGLE_SHEETS.
DRIVE_URI is your Drive URI.
DATASET is the name of the dataset that contains the table.
TABLE is the name of the table you're creating.
Once created, if you want to model, transform this data I would recommend you to use dataform (https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs), with SQL. Also, you can schedule runs at any time you want.
I hope this is helpful!
